# Can anyone explain to me what this query does?

Tags: mysql

I need the riposte in layman's language.

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
    , IF(isBranch='true','',IF(pointsweightage IS NULL,'Not Set',pointsweightage)) AS w
    , t2.id AS wid 
FROM 
    `skills_hierarchy` t1 LEFT JOIN 
    weightage t2 ON t1.pointsweightage=t2.weightage 
WHERE 
    isBranch='false' 
    AND t1.deptid=$deptid 
    AND t2.deptid=$deptid
```

I want the Query to be changed such that it gets me the data of the department which it does login.

Comment: Please clarify "the data of the department which it does login." I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Two things: First, I'm not sure I understand the line below the code correctly, you may want to edit and reformulate. Second, how are we supposed to know how to change the query without knowing anything about the table(s) you query?

Comment: by riposte do you mean explanation, or response, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to re-format this a bit to help you out, then I'll explain below.

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    IF(isBranch='true',
        '',
        IF(pointsweightage IS NULL,
            'Not Set',
            pointsweightage)) AS w,
    t2.id AS wid 
FROM `skills_hierarchy` t1 
    LEFT JOIN weightage t2 
        ON t1.pointsweightage=t2.weightage 
WHERE isBranch='false' 
    AND t1.deptid=$deptid 
    AND t2.deptid=$deptid
```

The "Select" portion gets you all values from the "skills_hierarchy" table, then a value for a column called "w".  This value will be one of three things.

1. An empty value if isBranch is equal to true
2. A Value 'Not Set' if pointsweightage is null
3. The value of pointsweightage if 1 and 2 do not apply

The query is already filtering out results based on a parameter value of $deptid

Comment: excellent, the problem here is i am not getting the other department ID values just t1.deptid works.... i was having a doubt over the query but now feel there is some flaw in my business logic. 

Thanks for explaining my own query again.